# Inject HTML into a VueJS template

Tags: vue.js, inject

I'm trying to "inject" HTML into my VueJS template to make things neater. For example:

Lets say this is my Content.vue

```
<template>
 <div class='content'>
    Hello content!
 </div>
 <div class='something'>
    <!-- I want to inject some HTML here! -->
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   // All the data, props and methods
 }
</script>
```

And in another file, I call my content.vue like this

```
<content></content>
```

This all works but what if I want to do something like

```
<content>
  <div class='injectme'>
    Lots of html stuff here
  </div>
</content>
```

is there a way to get the insides of `<content></content>` in the above case and inject it somewhere inside the `<template></template>`?

Note: I know I can use props but just asking because this would make things much easier.

Comment: You probably want to work with `slots`: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Slot-Content

Comment: @DerekPollard wow that looks exactly like what i need. Thanks alot!